# Setting the RVM path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I installed RVM, Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.9 on Lion which works fine. Only problem is, after I close the terminal I need to execute this:

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

for it to pick up RVM.I then need to make RVM use Ruby 1.9.2 first before I can do Rails stuff again.

How can I make this permanent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you first execute

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

you shouldn't need to do it again. That line appends the necessary file inclusion information RVM into your `.bash_profile`. If you are using `bash` (as opposed to zsh, ksh, csh, tcsh or any other shell), then RVM will be accessible each time you open a new session. If you are using a different shell, that line may need to be in a different startup file. For example, if you are using zsh, then you'll probably want to append it to your `~/.zshrc` file.

Having done this, simply running `rvm --default use ruby-1.9.2` once should ensure that you have the desired version of Ruby by default. Note, you should not need to add this line to your `.bash_profile` or similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this sorted it out.

Comment: Good to hear! If so, would you mind accepting this post as the answer so that I can get the reputation points? (just click the check mark box next to the post). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
rvm --default use ruby-1.9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make Terminal (e.g. bash) enable RVM every time you open it, edit `~/.profile` and add the following line to it:

```
[[ -s "/Users/foo/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/foo/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Then to make the RVM's version of ruby default, as fl00r has mentioned, run:

```
rvm --default use ruby-1.9.2
```

Alternatively, you can add an `.rvmrc` file to the root folder of your app that uses Rails 3.0.9 and specify which version of Ruby you want to use with that project there:

```
rvm ruby-1.9.2
```

Even better, you should create a gemset by running `rvm gemset create rails-3.0.9` and update you `.rvmrc` file to become like this:

```
rvm ruby-1.9.2@rails-3.0.9
```

Then run cd into the project once again (you must cd into it once again), and run bundle install.

This way your project will have its own isolated gemset.

Answer (score 0):

this also work for me

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```