# Why am I failing at ruby gems? I think it's something path related but I don't really know

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, path, rubygems, rvm

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but in my rails apps I keep getting errors that it can't find some gem, I bundle install, it still doesn't work, I try and see what version of ruby version i have on rvm so i type rvm and it can't find that either even though I installed it twice. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling things but I'm totally lost.

```
$ rails c
Could not find bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ rvm -version
-bash: rvm: command not found
```

It's a recurring problem for me that really slows me down. Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: What kind of system are you on? In your home directory, is there a directory called .rvm? What's the output of: echo $rvm_path ?

Answer (score 1):

this could be the answer?
[Rails: Could not find bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 in any of the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677604/rails-could-not-find-bcrypt-ruby-3-0-1-in-any-of-the-sources)

and for the RVM, if you are sure you installed it, make sure you have the path to it.
[Setting the RVM path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027784/setting-the-rvm-path)

or if you just installed RVM, then simply open a new terminal and check the version

`rvm --version`

Answer (score 1):

Start with installing RVM again:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --rails
```

Make sure to read all the outputs and follow instructions.

Then watch RVM screencast => http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm